# refresh activity from listadapter onclicklistener in android app

Tags: android, listview, click, textview, refresh

I have an activity with a listview in it. I implemented a custom list adapter based on ArrayAdapter. Some of the items within the list are clickable and some are not. So I implemented the onClickListener within the getView method of the listadapter.

I can refresh the listview just fine by calling the notifyDataSetChanged() method.

What I want to do is refresh the textview within the activity which contains the list whenever an item in the list is clicked. I can't think of a way to do this. Anybody have any suggestions?

This is what the activity contains:

1. TextView (Title)
2. TextView (total points) -> I want to update this
3. ListView (some items in the list are clickable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the reference of the TextView inside your CustomListAdapter, then trigger the update of the total points textview inside your onClickListener.

pseudo

```
getView() {
    onClickListener(Event..) {
      pointsTextView.setText(..points+1..)
    }

}
```

Comment: I used static methods and variables. I'm not sure if it's the best way, but the data I'm passing between activities have to be updated from different places, so I just made them static so I can access it from any activity. Thanks!